# moderncv error: Control sequence \g__hook_package/fontspec/after_reversed_tl already defined

Tags: moderncv

I am trying to use moderncv to write my resume, but encountered the following error

```
(C:\Users\HsiLu\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/microtype\microtype.sty

LaTeX hooks Warning: Generic hook 'package/after/fontspec' is deprecated.
(hooks)              Use hook 'package/fontspec/after' instead.


! LaTeX Error: Control sequence \g__hook_package/fontspec/after_reversed_tl
(LaTeX)        already defined.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...
```

My MME(minimal not working example actually) is

```latex
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme{classic}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
... what you’ll see in the next section
\end{document}
```

After googling and searching StackExchange, it seems not to find similar problem

PS: my environment is MikTeX + Windows10

Comment: Please check for updates. It seems you are using an out-dated `microtype` (and maybe other packages too). Don't forget: If you've installed MiKTeX for all users, you have to do the updates in admin *and* user mode of the MiKTeX console.

Comment: @cab Thanks for your comment. I updated in MiKTeX console but the problem remains, maybe this is not the cause of the problem

Comment: But with an up-to-date `microtype` the warning does not appear. So at least `C:\Users\HsiLu\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/microtype\microtype.sty` must be outdated. And maybe there are more outdated files. Please add `\listfiles` to the example and show the resulting `log` file.